# No SQL tab in spark history server for spark sql job

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, cloudera

I am using Cloudera 5.8.3 distribution which is built with spark 1.6.0. I submit a Spark job through oozie (it is submitted as a java action)

I can see the job successfully complete and can also find it on the Spark history server(which is also running for Spark 1.6.0). I can also see all the executor/application/jobs/stages/tasks level detail.

However, I also know that spark provides better logging for spark dataframes, I don't see that tab.
This is the view I'm talking about: [image: Sql Tab]

I'm unsure of what other details are relevant to this or where else to look for. Hoping to get some pointers.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQL Tab on history server is added in Spark 2.0.0. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11206

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure about this because I can see it on 1.6.0 (on the same history server for other jobs), and also on a local history server started via zepplein.

Comment: I'm not sure. If you are using the official Spark package, it's only available since 2.0.0. Some venders may patch their 1.6.0 Spark by themselves.